# How to run remote server shell script with environment parameters on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, ssh, jenkins

I am attempting to run a shell script on a remote server in jenkins scripted pipeline using the `sshScript remote: remote, script:` command.
This line of code currently looks like this:

```
sshScript remote: remote, script: './bash.sh' "$env.gitTag" "$env.Version"
```

However, it keeps saying that the parameters are null there is an error being thrown.  I have tried everything and cannot find an answer.  I echo the parameters before they are thrown and they contain strings which I expect.

```
15:56:35  WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep': script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command is null or empty
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:69)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

These are the errors being published at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a quoting issue.

```
sshScript remote: remote, script: "./bash.sh $env.gitTag $env.Version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understood the question right. Here are my thoughts:

Environment variables are only sent to the remote server through ssh if they are explicitly configured in `sshd_config` on the remote server. See the `AcceptEnv` parameter in `man sshd_config`.

By default it is usually set like this:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Which means only the "Language" environment is set to the remote host.

In your case you have to configure on the **remote server** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to accept the variables.